# Space partitioning to contain same amount of points

Tags: integer-partitions

Looking for an algorithm can partition space so, that each partition contains fix count of point i.e. 20 points. Which algorithm could solve problem?

Comment: Which space? $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Where are the points? How are the partitions done?